# How can I do a "git push" to remote with the gui gitx tool?

Tags: git

I come from linux and gitg.  That allows me to do the `git pull` and `git push` to the remote using the graphical gitg tool with a right-click option.  However the gitx tool doesn't seem to have this functionality.  Can I pull/push using gitx or do I have to use the command tool?
I couldn't find anything on the screen:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given no good answer in the past week - probably the product just doesn't have it -the "answer" for me was to start using the free SourceTree visual git tool.
It's amazing.  Once again gui tools have stepped up to another level.